# How To Change Specific Array Name In PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 166
    [role_code] => new role test
)
```

I want to change `[0]` into `[menu_id]`. How i can change it on PHP code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [union operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) and then unset index 0:

```
$array = [ 'menu_id' => $array[0] ] + $array;
unset($array[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign the value to a new item and unset the previous one.

```
$array['menu_id'] = $array[0];
unset($array[0]);
```

Comment: Do note that this would change the order of the array, menu_id would become the 2nd item in this case, while role_code would be the 1st.